# Can I replace name of Structure or Array in C?

Tags: c

I would like to know whether there is a way I can replace the name of a structure or array like below...

```
struct Node {
 char Branch[2];
 int Angle; 
};

struct Node A[]={{"F",135},{"D",135},{"G",90}};
.
.
.
.
.
char Des_Branch= "A";

(if Des_Branch[0].Branch == "F")
```

....... I would like to replace **A[0]** with **Des_Branch[0]**. Is there a way I can do it?

Thank you.

Comment: `replace` in the sense? change all the occurrences in the source code?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to refer to array A using some other name? Why dont you use pointers to refer to the the struct array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pointers for that

```
struct Node *Des_Branch = A;
```

but for comparing the contents of `Branch` member, you can't use the `==` operator, you need the `string.h` header and `strcmp`

```
if (strcmp(Des_Branch[0].Branch, "F") == 0)
```

and since it's just one character you could also do something like

```
if (Des_Branch[0].Branch[0] == 'F')
```

notice the single quotes in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#define` for that. Remove the line which reads

```
char Des_Branch= "A";
```

and add

```
#define Des_Branch A
```

to the file somewhere before the first use of `Des_Branch`. `#define`'s are often put at the beginning of the file.

Share and enjoy.